# Get a List of Date Between Two Date And Insert Data To DB

Tags: php, mysql, database

How do I get all the list of date between 2 dates for example

```
$start = 2019-11-20;
$end = 2019-11-23;
```

Output:

```
2019-11-20
2019-11-21
2019-11-22
2019-11-23
```

and on each returned date I want to insert a data and save the inserted data to the database with each returned date

expected:

```
2019-11-20 | Seminar
2019-11-21 | Seminar
```

and so on...

Comment: Your data set and desired result appear to bear little relationship to one another. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, this is straight-forward with a recursive common table expression:

```
insert into mytable(mydate, myval)
with recursive cte as (
    select '2019-11-20' dt
    union all 
    select dt + interval 1 day from cte where dt < '2019-11-23' 
)
select dt, 'Seminar' from cte
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5791a51b95c21085a764247bbe3078b)**

Table content after the query was executed:

```
mydate     | myval  
:--------- | :------
2019-11-20 | Seminar
2019-11-21 | Seminar
2019-11-22 | Seminar
2019-11-23 | Seminar
```

Comment: In the context of ready access to application code, this all seems rather unnecessary